# External file java script does not function

Tags: javascript

My code does not function in external file `<script src="action_input.js"></script>`.
I put this code in `<body></body>` or `<head></head>` and it does not function.

My code functions in `<body><script> code js</script></body>`, but not like so.
My code is:

```js
// identify form elements:
var search_code = document.getElementById('search_code');
var insert_code = document.getElementById('insert_code');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var audio = new Audio('sound.wav');


// respond to button click
button.onclick = function validate() {
    // show verification result:
    if(search_code.value == insert_code.value) {
        result.textContent = 'cod gasit';
        result.className = "ok";
        audio.play(); //http://soundbible.com/tags-winning.html
    } else {
       result.textContent = 'codul nu este corect';
       result.className = "not-ok";
    }
   // clear input when wrong:
    if (search_code.value !== insert_code.value) {
        insert_code.value = '';
    }
    return false;
};
//sterge textul cand se da click pe input
function clearField(input) {
         input.value = "";
};
```

My input is:

```html
     <form>
        <input type="text" name="search_code" onfocus="clearField(this, this.placeholder='');" onblur="this.placeholder='introdu codul'" id="search_code" placeholder="introdu codul" autocomplete="off" value=""/><br/>
        <input type="" name="insert_code" onfocus="clearField(this, this.placeholder='');" onblur="this.placeholder='scaneaza codul'" id="insert_code" placeholder="scaneaza codul" autocomplete="off" value=""/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" value="verifica COD" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent default action of `submit button` or use `type='button'`

There is no element having id `result`

Try this:

```js
var search_code = document.getElementById('search_code');
var insert_code = document.getElementById('insert_code');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var audio = new Audio('sound.wav');


// respond to button click
button.onclick = function validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // show verification result:
  if (search_code.value == insert_code.value) {
    result.textContent = 'cod gasit';
    result.className = "ok";
    audio.play(); //http://soundbible.com/tags-winning.html
  } else {
    result.textContent = 'codul nu este corect';
    result.className = "not-ok";
  }
  // clear input when wrong:
  if (search_code.value !== insert_code.value) {
    insert_code.value = '';
  }
  return false;
};
//sterge textul cand se da click pe input
function clearField(input) {
  input.value = "";
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="search_code" onfocus="clearField(this, this.placeholder='');" onblur="this.placeholder='introdu codul'" id="search_code" placeholder="introdu codul" autocomplete="off" value="" />
  <br/>
  <input type="" name="insert_code" onfocus="clearField(this, this.placeholder='');" onblur="this.placeholder='scaneaza codul'" id="insert_code" placeholder="scaneaza codul" autocomplete="off" value="" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" value="verifica COD" />
</form>
```

Comment: with `e.preventDefault();` my `button`, not function

Comment: If you want it as submit button then your JavaScript will not be executed as you will lose the control of the page..

Comment: my apologies, I put external file in <head></head>, but in <body></body>, my code function. Thank you @RayonDabre